# Reading even and odd lines fom file in php

Tags: php

I want to read data from a text file  d.txt. Then create 2 new text files,write a even line in a separate file e.txt and odd in another file o.txt.

```
 <?php
 $evenhandler = fopen("e.txt","w");        
 $oddhandler = fopen("o.txt","w");
 $handle = fopen('d.txt', 'r');
 while (!feof($handle))
   {
      $f=fgets($handle);
   fwrite($evenhandler,$f);
    }
  fclose($file); 

 ?>
```

Actually I didn,t understand how to implement it and according to my code no output was shown on screen.

Comment: Please give more information here. Is your solution not working? If so, please include error messages or expected/found output.

Comment: @ethrbunny. Ok next time I will be more careful in writing questions. So that these will me more clarified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
 $evenhandler = fopen("e.txt","w");        
 $oddhandler = fopen("o.txt","w");
 $handle = fopen('d.txt', 'r');
 $i=0;
 while (!feof($handle))
   {
      $f=fgets($handle);
      if($i%2==0)
      {
        fwrite($evenhandler,$f);
      }
      else
      {
        fwrite($oddhandler,$f);
      }
    $i++;
  }
  fclose($handle); 
  fclose($evenhandler); 
  fclose($oddhandler); 
?>
```

**Performance Tip:**

You can even further increase its performance (in case your input file is very big) . You can start with value of **$i** being as 0 and in the loop just check if it is 0 set it to 1 and vice versa. Then for your **if** you can just check if i = 1 or i =0 to make a decission. This way you can avoid using modulus operator in every pass and still get same result

Comment: Thanks Hanky Panky. I tried your code and it  solved my problem.

Comment: The solution is right, only it is written in an ugly way. See Malmanger's answer... Coding is more than typewriting... make it beautiful :)

Comment: "Ugly" is something subjective. Just shortening something doesnt make it "Beautiful" for me :). You have to cater for the expertise of who asked the question and make it easy for them, not who all are going to "take a look" at it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the modulus operator `%` helps you

```
 $outhandler[0] = fopen("e.txt","w");        
 $outhandler[1] = fopen("o.txt","w");
 $handle = fopen('d.txt', 'r');
 $linenum = 0;
 while (!feof($handle))
 {
    $f=fgets($handle);
    fwrite($outhandler[$linenum % 2],$f);
    $linenum++;
 }

fclose($handle);
fclose($outhandler[0]);
flcose($outhandler[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is actually really easy, and you've almost done that.
You only have to pass a different f.handler for even and odd rows.

```
<?php
$evenhandler = fopen("e.txt","w");        
$oddhandler = fopen("o.txt","w");
$data = file('d.txt'); // this reads entire file and puts it into array, each line separate item
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
  // Even shorter, if you put all this in only 1 line :)
  $fHandler = ($i%2==0)? $evenhandler:$oddhandler;
  fwrite($fHandler, $data[$i];
}
fclose($evenhandler); 
fclose($oddhandler);
?>
```

Comment: see Hanky Panky's answer. Your method is slower performance wise because you first read the whole file into an array. You can do it in a single pass with fgets()

Comment: I don't argue! It was just 1) easier, 2) nothing was mentioned performancewise...